# How to compare data in two workbooks row and column wise, add the data in destination workbook

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I've got two excel workbooks namely, "Source.xlsx" and "Target.xlsx" having data as:

**Source.xlsx**

```
  A      B      C      D         E
Signal  From    To  Conductor   Cable
#112    68      145   1        1935
#113    78      146   2        1936
#114    88      147   3        1937
#115    98      148   4        1938
#116    108     149   1        1939
#117    118     150   2        1940
#118    128     151   3        1941
#119    138     152   4        1942
#120    148     153   1        1943
#121    158     154   2        1944
```

**Traget.xlsx**

```
 A      B      C          D       E
From    To  Conductor   Signal  Cable
68     145                      1935
78     146                      1936
88     147                      1937
98     148                      1938
108    149                      1939
118    150                      1940
165    151                      1941
138    152                      1942
122    133                      1943
158    154                      1944
```

Requirements:

1. I want to compare data in both the excel workbooks (sheet 1 for
   both) row and column wise. If it matches, data from signal and
   conductor columns from Source will be added to Target file's Signal
   and Conductor Columns. The criteria for matching the data is 1st Row
   column B, column C and column E in source file and 1st Row column A,
   column B and column E respectively and so on.
2. Once data is copied, want to color that line green till data is filled in the cell.

I've tried the following code:

```
Sub E3ToEPlan()
' E3ToEPlan Macro
' Macro to Check/ Transfer data in E3 and EPlan Excel files

Dim sourcebook As Workbook, targetbook As Workbook
Dim sourcesheet As Worksheet, targetsheet As Worksheet
Dim sourcefilename As String, targetfilename As String

sourcefilename = "C:\Source.xlsx"
targetfilename = "C:\Target.xlsx"

Set sourcebook = Workbooks.Open(sourcefilename)
Set targetbook = Workbooks.Open(targetfilename)

Set sourcesheet = sourcebook.Worksheets(1)
Set targetsheet = targetbook.Worksheets(1)

Dim column_count As Long, row_count As Long
column_count = sourcesheet.Columns.Count
row_count = sourcesheet.Rows.Count
'sourcesheet.Range("A2:A9").Copy
'targetsheet.Range("D2:D9").PasteSpecial

'Condition to match the data in the other workbook
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
For i = 0 To column_count
    'For j = 0 To column_count
        If sourcesheet.Cells(i, 2).Value = targetsheet.Cells(i, 1).Value And sourcesheet.Cells( _
        i, 3).Value = targetsheet.Cells(i, 2).Value And sourcesheet.Cells(i, 5).Value = targetsheet _
        .Cells(i, 5) Then
            sourcesheet.Cells(i, 1).Value.Copy
            targetsheet.Cells(i, 4).Value.PasteSpecial
            sourcesheet.Cells(i, 4).Value.Copy
            targetsheet.Cells(i, 3).Value.PasteSpecial
            targetsheet.Cells(i, column_count).Interior.Color = vbGreen
        End If
    'Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

but it gives me error at If statement. [image: error]

Comment: initial value of `I` in the loop is `0` and you can't have `cells(0,2)`

Comment: Your need to have nested loops to find the right row in the second sheet,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested the code and it works.

There were a few issues:

- You cant use `Value.Copy` `Value` refers to the value inthe cell the result of a formula or a string of text
- `Columns.Count` counts all the `Columns` in the sheet, the same applies to `Rows`. I have added other code to determine the amount of used `Columns` and `Rows`
- The columns and rows in Excel start at 1 therefore there is no `Row` 0, which is used as a starting row for your `For i = 0 To column_count`, subsequently I have changed that to go from 1 to 'LastRow' which I assumed that you wanted to loop through every row.

See code below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub E3ToEPlan()
    ' E3ToEPlan Macro
    ' Macro to Check/ Transfer data in E3 and EPlan Excel files

    Dim sourcebook As Workbook, targetbook As Workbook
    Dim sourcesheet As Worksheet, targetsheet As Worksheet
    Dim sourcefilename As String, targetfilename As String

    sourcefilename = "C:\Source.xlsx"
    targetfilename = "C:\Target.xlsx"

    Set sourcebook = Workbooks.Open(sourcefilename)
    Set targetbook = Workbooks.Open(targetfilename)
    Set sourcesheet = sourcebook.Worksheets(1)
    Set targetsheet = targetbook.Worksheets(1)

    Dim LastColumn As Long
    LastColumn = sourcesheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Dim LastRow As Long
    With sourcesheet
        LastRow = .Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    End With

    'Condition to match the data in the other workbook
    Dim CurrentRow As Long
    Dim SourceShtColB As String, SourceShtColC As String, SourceShtColE As String
    Dim TargetShtColA As String, TargetShtColB As String, TargetShtColE As String

    For CurrentRow = 1 To LastRow

        SourceShtColB = sourcesheet.Cells(CurrentRow, 2).Value
        TargetShtColA = targetsheet.Cells(CurrentRow, 1).Value
        SourceShtColC = sourcesheet.Cells(CurrentRow, 3).Value
        TargetShtColB = targetsheet.Cells(CurrentRow, 2).Value
        SourceShtColE = sourcesheet.Cells(CurrentRow, 5).Value
        TargetShtColE = targetsheet.Cells(CurrentRow, 5).Value

        If SourceShtColB = TargetShtColA And _
            SourceShtColC = TargetShtColB And _
                SourceShtColE = TargetShtColE Then

            targetsheet.Cells(CurrentRow, 4) = sourcesheet.Cells(CurrentRow, 1)
            targetsheet.Cells(CurrentRow, 3) = sourcesheet.Cells(CurrentRow, 4)
            targetsheet.Cells(CurrentRow, LastColumn).Interior.Color = vbGreen

        End If

    Next CurrentRow
End Sub
```

Comment: @ Jean Your answer works correctly. Appreciate your response. Is there any other way i can set the color to entire row apart from the edit i've done in your answer?

Comment: Hello, @Divyanshu just change the last row of the last `If` statement to the following:  `targetsheet.Rows(CurrentRow).Interior.Color = vbGreen`